# Pegar sempre a segunda li

Tags: css

Galera, tenho algumas colunas, feitas com ul li

```
<ul>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

---

Que vai ficar assim no caso, de 2 em 2

```
[1] [2]
[1] [2]
[1] [2]
[1] [2]
[1] [2]
[1] [2]
```

Eu queria dar um `margin-left` de 15px mas eu queria somente que esse `margin-left` na coluna 2, ou seja, todos que for da coluna da direita >>> ter um margin-left.

Ja tentei com nth-child mas não deu muito certo.

Alguém saberia alguma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Com o `nth-child` você fez `li:nth-child(even)`?

Comment: Eu tentei com li:nth-child(2n) mas as vezes ele da o margin na coluna da esquerda <<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta você aplicar o estilo utilizando o seletor `nth-child(even)` para selecionar todos os elementos de índices pares (ou `odd` para os ímpares).

Veja um exemplo:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: green;
}

li:nth-child(even) {
  background: blue;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
</ul>
```